# OpenCart price issues

Tags: opencart

I've newly installed Open-Cart and I added my currency and deleted other currencies but when shown, the prices in the website are formatted with "decimal_point" in the middle, like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are your currency settings?

Answer (score 0):

Add your currency in Settings → Store as it will set your currency to default and even check if you have correctly submitted your currency values such as decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a setting for `$_['decimal_point']` in `catalog/language/klingon/klingon.php`, where "klingon" is the language to display your website in.  Note that for English the file is named `default.php`.

(I got the same issue after an upgrade, because I forgot to add files for my language.)